# crash while deleting rows from tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath, indexpath

[image: Please check in response data delete successfully but not removed from tableview and also when i run again then data not show beacuse its dele][image: Pelase check here i am deleting on yes button click]Hello i am i am deleting rows from tableview and its work fine for me i am successfully removed but after remove i am getting crash and error like below

**Error**

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and here i show you my code where i am getting crash

**Code**

```
@IBAction func btnDeleteYesTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!,"property_id": propertyID!,"occupants_id": oCCID!]
    print(params)
    Alamofire.request(propertyoccupantsdelete, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            print(response)
            let result = response.result.value
            print(response)
            let data = result as! [String : AnyObject]
            let status = data["success"] as! String
            if status == "1"{
                let buttonPosition : CGPoint = (sender as AnyObject).convert((sender as AnyObject).bounds.origin, to: self.tblOccList)
                let indexPath = self.tblOccList.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)! //At Here I am Getting crash 
                self.occuPantsData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.tblOccList.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                Toast(text: data["message"] as? String).show()
            }else{
              Toast(text: data["message"] as? String).show()
            }
    }
}
```

i am not able to understand why i am getting crash can any one please tell me where i am done something wrong

**Code For Showing Dialogue**

```
 @objc func handleLongPress(longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        let p = longPressGesture.location(in: self.tblOccList)
        let indexPath = self.tblOccList.indexPathForRow(at: p)

        if indexPath == nil {
            print("Long press on table view, not row.")
        }
        else if (longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
            print("Long press on row, at \(indexPath!.row)")
            let id = occuPantsData[indexPath!.row].id
            print(id)
            self.oCCID = id
            self.viewDeletePopUp.isHidden = false
        }

    }
```

Comment: what the result you get from this `buttonPosition`

Comment: You have lots and lots of force unwraps. Be very careful with those. It makes your app very prone to crashes and failure. Your problem here is that you are for unwrapping the indexPath but it is returning nil. `let indexPath = self.tblOccList.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)!` remove the `!` and `guard` unwrap it or unwrap it conditionally with `if let`

Comment: when i print `buttonPosition` i will get result like this (206.5, -63.0)

Comment: How are you planning to get an indexPath with a tuple? Thats why its crashing. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: i want to delete selected row on button click

Comment: if i use guard and is let then not able to delete rows from tableview

Comment: You are performing UI operations in an asynchronous block too; that isn't a good idea

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please suggest me another way to solve this

Comment: What is the context for the code shown?  Is it in the tableview or in the cell?  You have lots of force unwraps - that is bad.  You seem to be using user defaults for storing part of your data model - that is bad.  You should handle the button tap in your cell and have it notify the tableview of the tap via a delegation pattern.  You should immediately delete the item from your local array and delete the row from your tableview and then dispatch the network update to complete in the background

Comment: @VishalParmar Check my answer

Comment: It is not very robust to use the position on screen to recompute the indexPath. Should better attach a tag to each cell and use it to build the indexPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a property to save the selected indexPath before pop up the dialogue.

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
```

And change this

```
let indexPath = self.tblOccList.indexPathForRow(at: p)

        if indexPath == nil {
            print("Long press on table view, not row.")
        }
```

To

```
self.selectedIndexPath = self.tblOccList.indexPathForRow(at: p)

        if self.indexPath == nil {
            print("Long press on table view, not row.")
        }
```

Then try changing this

```
let indexPath = self.tblOccList.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)!
```

to

```
guard let indexPath = self.selectedIndexPath else { return }
```

Comment: if i am replacing with your code i am getting error lik this `Cannot convert value of type 'PropertyDetailViewController' to expected argument type 'UITableViewCell'`

Comment: I am showing popup on tableview cell long press and then i am deleting the row if their any possibility for that this crash in getting

Comment: no the delete button on popup means on long press of cell i am showing popup for confirm delete and then on yes button i am deleting

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope that help

Comment: please check image i am  getting success response but still row not removed from tableview and when i run again then data doesn't appear beacuse its deleted

Comment: Do you saved the clicked cell to selectedCell?

Comment: where i want to save clicked cell to selected cell not able to understand

Comment: Can you post the code of showing the popup dialogue?

Comment: Please check i Updated question

Comment: Please give me solution if you understand whats the issue

Comment: `self.indexPath = self.tblOccList.indexPathForRow(at: p)

        if self.indexPath == nil {
            print("Long press on table view, not row.")
        }`in this from where you can get `self.indexPath`

Comment: The idea is save the clicked row instead of recalculation

Comment: It’s my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Add in tableview cellForRowAt delegate method assign button tag to indexPath.row

```
     cell.button.tag = indexPath.row 

    @IBAction func btnDeleteYesTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!,"property_id": propertyID!,"occupants_id": oCCID!]
    print(params)
    Alamofire.request(propertyoccupantsdelete, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            print(response)
            let result = response.result.value
            print(response)
            let data = result as! [String : AnyObject]
            let status = data["success"] as! String
            if status == "1"{                
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
                self.occuPantsData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.tblOccList.reloadData()
                Toast(text: data["message"] as? String).show()
            }else{
              Toast(text: data["message"] as? String).show()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: this not working its give me crash on same where i am getting

Comment: No you can check just two lines you have to add after success and assign indexPath.row to button.tag